# Why do we say "shelo asani isha" everyday?

Tags: blessing, women, shacharis-morning-prayer, men-male

Why is it that we say shelo asani isha/sheasani kirtzono every day? Presumably we would only need to thank Hashem once for making us the gender he made us.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Zohar, the soul leave the body during sleep every night. In fact, there is actually a small chance that the wrong soul returns in the morning. Thus, there is the possibility of receiving the wrong "gendered" soul, and so we thank Hashem every day.

Comment: If anyone can find the actual source in the Zohar that would be great! I just heard it at a shabbat table.

Comment: This is also kind of an answer to trans-gender people min hatorah minayin....